# Simple contact form with file upload, which sends file and message to an email address

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I'm looking to build simple contact form with file upload, which sends a file, email and message to another email address. I would preferably do this in Ajax and post the email, message and file to another email. Are there any resources or tutorials on how to do this? Because I have no clue.

so far I have the following:

```
var departmentEmail = 'contact.php';
var email = $('#email').val();
var message = $('.message').val();

 var contactData = {  email: email, message: message};

                $.post(departmentEmail, contactData, function(data){

                 });
```

But not sure how to do all the file sending etc.

Comment: The jQuery Forms plugin supports AJAX file uploads.  But be aware that some browsers don't handle AJAX file uploads correctly, or handle it in different ways.  It's still relatively new as far as browser versions are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably help you a bit http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

Comment: How about http://www.html-form-guide.com/email-form/php-email-form-attachment.html  Google is a wonderful invention